# CSS style override default textbox border to create invisible border?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, css, razor

I want to display a text box in css/razor without the border (well, as white background) but it's picking up the color value from it's parent.

**Q:** How can I override the default value in the parent css style so my textbox value looks like a label (white background color)?

```
input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"], select {
border: 1px solid #93A9C8;  }

.TextBoxAsLabel
{
   border: none;
   background-color: #fff;
   background: transparent;
}
```

-- Called from razor page --

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImpToDate, new { @class = "TextBoxAsLabel" })
```

Comment: wait so what does it look like now?

Comment: border: 0; didn't do anything.  The border style value is still being inherited.

Comment: have you tried input.TextBoxAsLabel?

Comment: $! input.TextBoxAsLabel worked! Thanks corroded!  =)

Comment: no prob, posted the answer again for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: `input.TextBoxAsLabel`

This makes your class more specific and will probably override the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the border value from none to 0 (zero)

Comment: No go! The style is still being overriden from the input[type="text"] style.

Comment: Can you set a class/id to the default so it won't overide?